# Placeholder doesn't update option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```js
$(function() {
  var myOption= $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
 $("#search").attr("placeholder", myOption);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="search" id="search">
</form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

It would be a easy solution for you but i just stuck on this.
Why placeholder doesn't update option value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code only runs once after the page loads. To make it run when the select is changed, add an event listener to re-run your code with the new value.

```js
$(function() {
  function setPlaceholder() {
    var myOption= $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
    $("#search").attr("placeholder", myOption);  
  }
  setPlaceholder();
  $("#mySelect").change(setPlaceholder);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="search" id="search">
</form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```